# Flutter Better way to add Providers in main.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

In main.dart file I always have to add the same thing with different class name to make things works, here is an example.

```
MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductDataProvider>(
                create: (_) => ProductDataProvider()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthenticationProvider>(
                create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider()),
          ],
          child: Container())
```

If we have 20 providers let's say then there is a lot duplicate code there right. Is any work around this?

Answer (score 1):

See, if it is about initializing your provider in your `main.dart`, I am afraid, you have to do it, cos it need those.
For any duplicates, you can make use of some short tricks and get going.

> 1. Create an Array consisting of all your ChangeNotifiers, like in this case: `ProductDataProvider` and `AuthenticationProvider`

```
List<ChangeNotifier>_providersArray = [ProductDataProvider, AuthenticationProvider];
```

> 2. Now, when you have the array, add it to the array which adds the `ChangeNotifier`, to your final `providers` list.

```
// This will be your array of Providers, which you will add to Mutliprovider(providers: HERE)
List<Provider> providers = []; // make sure you have the right type of the List<>, which the `providers` in `Multiproviders` accepts

for(var provider in _providersArray){
  //adding the provider name to the ChangeNotifier
  providers.add(ChangeNotifierProvider<provider>( create: (_) => provider()));
}
```

> 3. Finally passing the providers in your `Multiprovider`

```
MultiProvider(
   providers: providers,
   child: Container()
)
```

**Max to max, you will have to do the type casting for some type mismatches, and you're good to go**. Let me know if that helps you in anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, I was wondering if there is any way to even do it better approach with get_it package we register the providers with it, I'm not sure if it's practically possible or not

Comment: I guess so @AtiqUrRehman. But I felt like this would do the job for now, and later you can go ahead with any approaches. If you feel like this is kinda workable, you can `mark it as correct` or `up vote it` or `do both`. Your call :) It would at least help somebody to some extent

Comment: Yes, not a bad idea for now